# Castle Windsor Property Injection does not work with dynamic parameters

Tags: castle-windsor, nservicebus

We want to use NserviceBus Saga's and in order to do that you need parameterless constructors for your saga. The only other way to inject our concerns is to use property injection which does not appear to work. Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I have posted sample code below that show's the issue.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();

        container.Register(Component.For<ClassWithDynamicProperty>()
            .DynamicParameters((r, k) =>{ k["testString"] = "test"; }) );

        container.Register(
            Component.For<TestClassWithPropertyInjection>());

        container.Register(
            Component.For<TestClassWithConstructorInjection>());

        var class1 = container.Resolve<TestClassWithConstructorInjection>();
        var class2 = container.Resolve<TestClassWithPropertyInjection>();

        Debug.Assert(class1.DynamicClass == null);
        Debug.Assert(class2.ClassWithDynamicProperty == null);

    }
}

internal class TestClassWithPropertyInjection
{
    public TestClassWithPropertyInjection()
    {

    }

    public ClassWithDynamicProperty ClassWithDynamicProperty { get; set; }
}

internal class TestClassWithConstructorInjection
{
    private readonly ClassWithDynamicProperty _classWithDynamicProperty;

    public TestClassWithConstructorInjection(ClassWithDynamicProperty classWithDynamicProperty)
    {
        _classWithDynamicProperty = classWithDynamicProperty;
    }

    public ClassWithDynamicProperty DynamicClass { get { return _classWithDynamicProperty; }  }

}

public class ClassWithDynamicProperty
{
    public string TestString { get; private set; }

    public ClassWithDynamicProperty(string testString)
    {
        TestString = testString;
    }
}
```

Comment: In v5 you no longer need to have a default ctor in Sagas, you can just do ctor injection

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Will have a look and will let you know if it works.